# Run NextJs application without a server from local file system

Tags: next.js

I have a static web application built using NextJs 13, it has no API paths and no data fetching. Is it possible to run the website from the local file system with no server?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load static pages individually, but routing between pages did not work.

Firstly I needed to get static files generated during the build. I updated my `package.json` to do `next export` after the build like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "next build && next export"
}
```

When I run the build (`yarn build` in my case) I then got a folder called `out` in my project root folder.

I had an `out/index.html` file which I can open in my browser. However, much of my content did not load correctly. Looking in the network tab when I reloaded this page, I could see lots of failed calls to get various css and javascript files. The failed urls were pointing to locations like `file:///_next/...`. These files did exist in my out folder, its just the the index page is looking for them on the wrong path.

I was able to fix this by adding `assetPrefix: "./"` to my `next.config.js` file. Here is that file in full for me:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  assetPrefix: "./",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I ran the build again, and this time when I opened out/index.html my website page worked fine. I could not route between pages though. If you needed some specific links to work you could replace the React routing with a html link, but of course you no longer have a Single Page Application at that point.

In my case I just needed to share a single page in-browser tool with someone so the process was still useful.